# Algorithm to get aspect ratio of a irregular shape

Tags: c#, math, image-processing, computational-geometry

I am developing an image analysis app and I need to calculate the aspect ratio of a segmented particle.

According to 
http://www.sympatec.com/Science/Characterisation/05_ParticleShape.html
the AR is given by (FIG 1)  Xfmin/Xfmax.

Any suggestion of an algorithm to get this values (Xf)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want the width and diameter of a concave polygon. Maybe you can use the [rotating caliper](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/maxd2p.html) algorithm for that, maybe after splitting your concave polygon in a number of convex polygons.